# How to pass enum to method by reference

Tags: ios, objective-c

Here is the brief code:

```
 enum datatype {
    type1 = 0,
    type2 = 1
 } myDataType;
```

in .m file:

```
 @property (nonatomic) myDataType dateType;

 -(void)foo:(myDatatype)type
 {
     type = type2;
 }

 -(void)doSomething
 {
      self.dataType = type1;
      [self foo:self.dataType]
      NSLog(@"data type: %d), self.dataType);
 }
```

the print out always type1.  I want to the self.dataType change to type2 as foo: method indicates.  How can I do it?  Do I need to pass by pointer?  Thanks.

Comment: Another good argument to learn C first ...

Answer (score 1):

Pass the pointer to enum. Your method should look as follows:

```
-(void)foo:(myDatatype*)type
{
     *type = type2; 
}
```

And method's call: `[self foo:&self.dataType]`

Comment: You can't pass the address of a property.

Answer (score 0):

You have set the `dataType` variable as `property` already.

```
 @property (nonatomic, assign) myDataType dataType;
```

So you can simply access that variable inside any method in your class. What is the need of passing it as a parameter or its pointer?

```
-(void)foo {
  self.dataType = type2;
}
```